# String upto first non white space character in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsscanner

I have a string like

```
 NSString * aString = @"\n    \n    \n   This is my string  ";
```

I need to extract firs blank spaces and new line characters upto first non-whitespace non-newline character. that is the output should be

```
NSString *output = @"\n    \n    \n   ";
```

I tried it with `NSScanner` as follows
 NSString * aString = @"\n    \n    \n   This is my string  ";

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSString *output = nil;
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:characterSet intoString:&output];
```

But after execution the output string is nil. whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to match all whitespaces (\s*) in the begining of the line (^):

```
NSString *string = @"\n    \n    \n   This is my string  ";
NSRegularExpression *expression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^\\s*" options:0 error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [expression firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
NSString *output = [string substringWithRange:match.range];
```

Comment: Ok.. its working perfectly. Thank you for answer. Btw do you have any idea about what the problem with my NSScanner implementation?

Comment: Also what I need to do for finding same from end of the striog?

Comment: I tried to do something with your scanner, but I have no idea what is wrong there. You can use @"\\s*$" for finding same at the end ($ stands for end)